# Different results when using WebRequest vs WebClient

Tags: c#, webclient, webrequest

We have a text file that gets generated automatically and put in a web server. The task is to read the file line by line and insert the records in a database. The following code is in C#:

```
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            StreamReader r = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

            while (r.Peek() > -1)
            {
                string s = r.ReadLine().Trim();
                //insert string into a db.
            }
```

When I do this I constantly get the entire file which ranges from 9000 - 10000 lines. On the other hand when I  use the following sometimes I get a truncated file (less lines)

```
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            StreamReader r = new StreamReader(client.OpenRead(url));

            while (r.Peek() > -1)
            {
                string s = r.ReadLine().Trim();
                //insert string into a db.
            }
```

Can anyone explain the difference? Why would the results be different? I was under the impression that WebClient was just a wrapper of HttpWebRequest.

Comment: The WebClient OpenRead method is a wrapper around WebRequest.  In fact it looks nearly identical to the WebRequest code you posted.  I checked WebCLient in ILSpy to confirm.  I suspect the problem lies elsewhere.  Can you debug and confirm that the lines you are reading are what you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using `Peek` method, you are guaranteed to have a complete line ready to be red.

I bet you are getting partial lines (actually breaking at the current stream position).

In fact, I don't think it's related to either of the two class, but more to how you read the result.

Did you tried [WebClient.DownloadString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.net.webclient.downloadstring.aspx) method ?

Comment: This is good idea (using the DownloadString() method) and then splitting the string into separate records to insert. It works.

Comment: just be careful about the length of the string... if the target is very very very long (several MB), you will have to wait that the whole file is download, and your memory consumption will be high